# I have got a problem checking a condition and write the answer into a new column

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, if-statement

I have a column called "score_differential". I want to write a "1" into the new column "home_win" if the number is positive and a "0" if the number is negative. Result is the name of my new DataFrame.

This is my try

```py
result.loc[i,"home_win"]=if result["score_differential"] > 0:
                                print("1")
                                else:
                                    print("0")
```

But this gives me the error "invalid_syntax".
I am new to python so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.where()`

```
result["home_win"] = np.where(result["score_differential"]>=0 , "1","0")
```